# Subversion commit failed - how to solve?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to commit to an SVN repository (using Windows TortoiseSVN) and the response is:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
File already exists: filesystem 'F:\svn_repository\db', transaction '5150-43c',
 path '/PROJECT43/src/android.app/branch'
```

I've tried doing an Update of the whole project. I've also tried a Clean. Neither helped.

As far as I can tell no changes were made to, or in, the repository folder that is mentioned (branch).

The error message means nothing to me. Does it to you, and what is the solution?

Comment: file:/// repo on network drive?

Comment: What is URL of your repository and where it **physically** placed?

Comment: The question includes its location: F:\svn_repository\db

Comment: Is F: local or mapped network drive?

Comment: I do not manage the server, so at this point I cannot confirm. Could the location of the repository cause this error?

Comment: No, my assumptions was totally wrong. See answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. /branch directory exist earlier in your project, but was removed in some old revision
2. You added this directory by hand, but SVN "knows" about this (old) directory

I **think**, you have to remove handmade dir, re-create it as local by `svn mkdir` and try to commit empty dir

Alternative solution (possible) starting from p.2 is create dir *on repo directly*, `svn up`, add content, commit

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. Re-creating the folder and trying a commit produces the same error. what does it actually mean?

Comment: @OllieC - means exactly written - you *had* this directory before

Comment: that doesn't help. Nothing about that directory has changed. It was created weeks ago, and no-one has touched it. Commits worked fine. Suddenly they don't, and the error referenced a folder that's not been touch.

Comment: @OllieC - ok, what about `svn status`, `svn log -v PROJECT43/src/android.app/branch`